# Heat map from multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, heatmap

I'm trying to generate a heat map from two multidimensional arrays (199,199) in python. When executing the function, this is the error I get:

File "/home/jorge/Escritorio/Jorge/scripts/energy_landscape/energy_landscape.py", line 265, in heat_map
    Xi = np.r_[rvs[:,0].min():rvs[:,0].max():199j]
IndexError: too many indices

I guess that's because of the huge size of the data. How could I deal with it?
Here the code I've used:

```
def heat_map(RMSD, E):
    rvs = np.append(RMSD, E)
    kde = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(rvs.T)

    Xi = np.r_[rvs[:,0].min():rvs[:,0].max():199j]
    Yi = np.r_[rvs[:,1].min():rvs[:,0].max():199j]
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
    grid_coords = np.append(X.reshape(-1,1), Y.reshape(-1,1), axis = 1)

    Z = kde(grid_coords.T)
    Z = z.reshape(199,199)

    scatter(rvs[:,0], rvs[:,1], alpha=1 ,color='white')
    plot = imshow(Z, aspect=Xi.ptp()/Yi.ptp(), origin='lower', extent=(rvs[:,0].min(), rvs[:,0].max(), rvs[:,1].min(), rvs[:,1].max()))

    return plot
```

Thanks! ;)

Note: RMSD and E are (199,199) python lists